# JavaScript Script Taking Too Long to Execute. Getting the Script Taking Too Long Prompt

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function buildTable which builds a very long HTML table.

```
 function buildTable() {

                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

     .. code to create table

}
```

}

The buildToolsetTable takes too much time and after few seconds IE 7 shows the prompt that if I want to keep running the script. I read that I can use window.setTimeout to make another call and refresh the execution but if someone has implementation then it will be super helpful.

Comment: This question barely a question... Can you post some more code?

Comment: @ close voters - it's completely obvious what the underlying question is - it's just worded badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this which breaks the loop up into a separate function that's called for each iteration:

```
(function(n) {
    var i = 0;

    function doWork() {
        // do one row's worth of stuff here
        ...

        if (++i < n) {
            setTimeout(doWork, 0);
        } else {
            // do your tidy up here
            ...
        }
    }

    doWork(); // start the first iteration
})(rowCount);
```

Calling `setTimeout()` will allow the browser to intersperse UI event handling with your own code.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/8wXTT/

For added fun, make the single iteration and tidy up functions callbacks, so you can make this code standalone and just pass in the required parameters.

Comment: Inside doWork() I have a for loop which iterates through all the rows. How can I break it up. Will I not loose the index position of the loop.

Comment: @Alnitak `setInterval` - sure? That would create `rowCount` "timer" which will call `doWork` as soon as possible until the window gets closed. `setTimeout` should be the better choice

Comment: @azamsharp the "do some stuff" is where you do _one_ iteration of the loop

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks a lot! That problem is solved but I am having some other index related issues. I will check them out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Alnitak, I like this solution, but I don't fully understand what you mean by tidying up. Would that be keeping a reference to all the timers (return value of `setTimeout`) and "_null'ing_" them in the `else` block?

Comment: @BartVG no, it mostly means to initiate whatever code has to be done _after_ this loop at that point (since if you do it outside of this IIFE it'll start immediately after the first iteration).)

Comment: cAN YOU POST THE WORKING CODE